# Having a trouble on java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a test.jar package and a Test.java file in the same folder(it is not in my CLASSPATH).

In the `.java` file I import some classes that are in the .jar package.
So I go the that folder, use `java -classpath test.jar Test.java` to compile. Everything looks good. Then I use `java Test`, it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:......
```

saying that it cannot find the classes inside the .jar file.

I move the file to Eclipse and add the jar file, it works.

Comment: have you tried: `java -classpath test.jar Test` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as you compiled the code using `javac -classpath test.jar Test.java` you should use the java command to run (add the jar file in the classpath) 
`java -classpath test.jar Test.java`

Comment: you need to be a bit more descriptive of the problem.. what is the exception/error trace? is it the same error as before?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test/jav
a
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Teest.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: Test.java.  Program will exit.

Comment: try `java -jar test.jar Test`

Comment: but I obviously have main class in the Test.java file

Comment: i meant try Test without the .java part.. that could be a reason.. also if the Test class is inside a package you need to use the fully qualified java class for instance `com.example.Test`

Comment: I tried java -jar test.jar Test. it says "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from test.jar"

Comment: that was my mistake... try this `java -classpath test.jar Test`

Comment: I tried java -classpath trendulate.jar TrendulateAPITest. It gives me "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test"

Comment: you may need to include the jar file which contains a class called `Test`, here the class doesn't seem to be in the jar.. it may be within a package.

Comment: Does that mean I can not never run my Test.java if I put the .jar file and the .java file in the same folder, and So I have to put the .java file INTO the .jar package? I understand that it is possible to run a class inside a .jar package, but why it's not working if the class and the .jar are in the same folder?

Comment: Does that mean I can not never run my Test.java if I put the .jar file and the .java file in the same folder, and So I have to put the .java file INTO the .jar package? I understand that it is possible to run a class inside a .jar package, but why it's not working if the class and the .jar are in the same folder?

Comment: the class fine needs to be in a package to be identified properly.. you don't need to jar the file (however its advisable), just put it in a package and start it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You must run the `java` command with the classpath too, same as the compiler.